# Cortana not invoking my ChatBot

Tags: azure, chatbot, cortana

I have registered my chatbot on Cortana . But when I invoke my chatbot from Cortana by saying "Ask MyBotName" its telling me something went wrong. Is there anyone who has deployed app on Cortana or knows how it is to be deployed

Comment: Are you sure cortana is using the same MS account as the one you used to publish?

Comment: Yes I am using the same MS account which I used to publish the bot.